# How do I combat enemies in the water?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Is there any way to kill swimming enemies in the water? I can't seem to find any way to deal with them while I'm swimming in the open water.

The only thing I can think of doing is coaxing them near the shore but they don't seem to come onto land.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The only thing you can use in water is your crossbow

Comment: That is correct. The game already explains that Geralt can not fight or use signs underwater, only his crossbow.

Comment: Also note that the crossbow is Insaine underwater. I cant say specific numbers or levels, but it was rare if ever that it took more than 2 shots to kill a drowner.

Answer (score 18):

You can't use signs underwater, but if you use Quen before you enter the water, the effect will stay and you can deflect one hit. With the "Exploding Shield" ability it will also knock back the attacking enemies.

This is how I dealt with underwater enemies that were close to treasure, to have enough time to grab the loot and get out of there.

Answer (score 12):

**You can only use your crossbow to "fight" underwater**.

The crossbow can kill them with one hit, **or** throw them off and make them go away, depends on the game's difficulty level.

**Be reminded that the crossbow doesn't always kill one-shot**.

More than once I've tried killing drowners underwater at lvl. 37 and I was lvl. 40 and they died with 2 hits. I've experienced this in Skellige as well as Toussaint from the Blood & Wine DLC.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: I was not the one that downvoted, but shooting your crossbow underwater will 1shot the drowners.

Comment: I've tried it and it didn't kill the drowners. it just made them go away. I was level 10 at the time and so were the Drowners.

Comment: Did you go completely underwater? Because while swimming and not diving it will not work, but if you are completely underwater then it does. When I had to do it I was lvl 7 and the drowners were level 10, and I was still 1shotting them.

Comment: Maybe It has something to do with the difficulty levels? I could imagine that On higher difficulties it scares them off while on lower levels it kills them completely.

Comment: I'm on Blood and Broken Bones. @Jutschge Yeah maybe it's the difficulty

Comment: @Lokuzt No special ammo, but I was using a lvl 7 crossbow I found. And my difficulty is the normal mode. So it could have something to do with it indeed.

Comment: The game automatically switches you to the default infinite ammo when you go underwater. Take a look at the stats of the default ammo when you're underwater; it gets buffed up to like 400 silver damage or something ridiculous.

Comment: I'm playing on Death March difficulty and a shot with the first crossbow I got took about two thirds of a drowner's health (I think around level 8) underwater, so it does much more damage than on land and it didn't scare them away.

Comment: As it stands, the answer is wrong since most people won't play the hardest level possible. If you want, fix the answer by stating it's relevant only for the hardest difficulty level. (in other levels, bolts kills enemies just fine.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've updated my answer with my knowledge of the game. I know my answer is correct because just this week I had experience with this.

Comment: Still not clear it's related to the difficulty level, I've added my own edit suggestion.

Comment: @ShadowWizard approved it

Comment: Cheers, now it's correct and giving extra details not mentioned in the other answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the crossbow and shoot them underwater.

The problem for me is I thought that I would one-shot kill them underwater but it only took out around half of their health... Also Geralt takes too damn long to reload another arrow... I was level 3 and the drowner was level 10.  And I was playing on easy mode.  And I got killed when I wanted to get the spoils of war.

Answer (score -1):

I just killed the under water creatures by using the cross bow under water.

The way to do it, is to swim out just enough for them to notice you, then shoot the cross bow directly at them once or twice to get their attention.

Then swim towards the shore while they chase you, go onto the land to escape and then go right back in the water and repeat the process until they're dead.

Comment: This was already answered long before you posted this. Repeating it is just noise.

Answer (score -4):

You have to "R3" them and then it oneshots them.

Comment: Please add a comment to contribute to discussion, rather than providing a low quality answer. An answer of this nature is likely to be downvoted.

Comment: What does R3 do? Melee them?

Comment: @Robotnik. R3 should be the quick-item-use button. In this case it most likely refers to the crossbow.

Comment: @Nolonar No, R3 locks on to enemies. He means that doing that and then shooting without aiming one-shots them, but I don't think it makes a difference whether you lock on. I haven't tried it though.

Comment: R3 is also a brand of condoms. This answer is really, really, bad.